# Launching SASS as a daemon from Chef Cookbook

Tags: ruby, sass, chef-infra, vagrant

I was hoping for some guidance on launching SASS --watch as a daemon from a Chef Cookbook. The following doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
lib="/vagrant/lib"
sassPath="#{lib}/sass"

include_recipe 'ruby'

execute 'install-sass' do
    command 'gem install sass'
end

execute "mkdir-lib" do
    not_if {File.exists?(lib)}
    command "mkdir #{lib}"
end

execute "mkdir-sass" do
    not_if {File.exists?(sassPath)}
    command "mkdir #{sassPath}"
end

execute "create-procfile" do
    command "nohup sass --watch #{sassPath}:#{lib} &"
end
```

Chef completes successfully. There just doesn't seem to be a way to run sass --watch as a service.

Output from Chef:

```
[default] Running chef-solo...
stdin: is not a tty
[2012-12-19T19:39:44+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 10.14.2 ***
[2012-12-19T19:39:27+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[ruby]",         "recipe[sass]"] from JSON
[2012-12-19T19:39:27+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[ruby], recipe[sass]]
[2012-12-19T19:39:27+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [ruby, sass]
[2012-12-19T19:39:27+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for precise64
[2012-12-19T19:39:27+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2012-12-19T19:39:27+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2012-12-19T19:39:27+00:00] INFO: Processing execute[apt-update] action run (ruby::default line 1)
[2012-12-19T19:39:40+00:00] INFO: execute[apt-update] ran successfully
[2012-12-19T19:39:40+00:00] INFO: Processing package[ruby] action install (ruby::default line 5)
[2012-12-19T19:39:57+00:00] INFO: Processing execute[install-sass] action run (sass::default line 6)
[2012-12-19T19:40:54+00:00] INFO: execute[install-sass] ran successfully
[2012-12-19T19:40:54+00:00] INFO: Processing execute[mkdir-lib] action run (sass::default line 10)
[2012-12-19T19:40:54+00:00] INFO: Processing execute[mkdir-sass] action run (sass::default line 15)
[2012-12-19T19:40:54+00:00] INFO: Processing execute[create-procfile] action run (sass::default line 20)
[2012-12-19T19:40:54+00:00] INFO: execute[create-procfile] ran successfully
[2012-12-19T19:40:54+00:00] INFO: Chef Run complete in 87.021831 seconds
[2012-12-19T19:40:54+00:00] INFO: Running report handlers
[2012-12-19T19:40:54+00:00] INFO: Report handlers complete
```

Comment: Can you attach the chef run output? It may be as simple as not having sass in the path.

Comment: Which chef output would you like to see?

Also just to clarify, I can launch the SASS --watch if I ssh into the virtual machine, but would like to have it enabled and running directly from the chef script without the need for intervention.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am facing somehting similar

Comment: Unfortunately, I never did find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

When you run a command, that command is executed as a [child process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_process) of the parent Chef Client process. In linux-land, child processes are terminated when their parent dies.

If you are running Chef Client as a script (like cron or manually), the parent process is that script. So even if you background the child process, it is killed with the parent process dies . In this case, this occurs when the Chef Client run completes.

Running scripts with `&` in the background is never a recommended approach, especially in production. Instead, you should wrap the SASS watcher as an `init.d` or service and then use Chef's native `service` resource.

You might also look into demonizing the SASS watcher, which would detach the process from the parent, allowing it to survive after the run completes. However, if you do this, you'll need to manually manage the PID files - otherwise you'll spin a new process each Chef Client run.